# PermGen Space Error while running Maven Build

Tags: java, out-of-memory, java-7, permgen

I have a requirement to upload a document to SharePoint by converting a .txt file to Excel and then send the document to a REST service by converting the excel into a byteArray.

The implementation was done and the code is working fine, however I have a written a simple Junit class which runs without any issue when I run as Junit but when I run my application as a maven build I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error`.  If I just ignore this test class the build is getting successful. I have no clues why this test class is causing the perm gen space issue.

I have tried increasing the perm gen space in environment variables, Maven pom.xml and eclipse configuration file but no luck.

Sample test case:

```
public void testUploadRenewalReportToSharePoint() throws Exception {

    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("renewal_DOC1_log.txt");
    byte[] byteArray = renewalLetterDoc1Service.generateRenewalReport(inputStream);

    assertEquals(
            "XXXX/RenewalReport_September_2017.xls",
            sharePointService.upload(byteArray, "RenewalReport_September_2017.xls").getPath());

}
```

Could someone please help me root cause of the issue?

Comment: When you say increasing the perm gen size did not help, did you validate that it was indeed bigger after your configuration change?  It might still be too small.  Look at your GC logs (or use jconsole) and validate your increase.

Comment: Thanks Nic, I was able to fix by adding the below configuration in my pom.xml. Earlier I only increased the Perm Gen space but now increased the heap memory as well, so it worked.

<configuration>
         <argLine>-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m</argLine>
      </configuration>

Comment: ok.  You can answer your question yourself, so if users search for this in the future, they will have an answer right away.

Comment: Yes Nic, thank you!! Appreciate your help!!